# Cannot doubleclick binary file to make it run in terminal

Tags: linux, ubuntu-11.04

I've made a script like so:

```
#! /bin/bash
/path/to/program
```

and made it executable. I want to be able to double click on it in Nautilus, choose "run in terminal" and everything should be the same as when I invoke the script myself from the terminal, where it works fine. When I double click though, I get the error message "error while loading shared libraries: libpylonbase-2.3.3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory" and the terminal closes immediately. libpylonbase-2.3.3 has to do with an industrial camera that is used within the program. Can anyone see the reason for it working it one of the cases and not in the other?

Comment: This question is probably a better fit (and would generate a better answer) on http://unix.stackexchange.com/ or http://askubuntu.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that the environment variables are the same when you run your program from the terminal and from Nautilus. You can do this by inserting the following line:

```
env > /tmp/test
```

At least $PATH and $LD_LIBRARY_PATH should be the same.

Comment: Cool! I only needed to copy some exports from my .bashrc

Comment: I don't see why the environments are different though.

Comment: Check your .bashrc file. It might have something like `[ -z "$PS1" ] && return`. Everything after that point is only executed when running interactive sessions, i.e., in a terminal.

Comment: Yep, this was the case, thank you,  so is there any drawback to just comment it out?

Comment: I wouldn't comment it out. First, it slows things down (why would anybody load bash_completion rules for non-interactive sessions). Second, it might break things. For example, I have aliases which change "grep" and "rm". I think it is best to move environment variable assignments before that line.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably LD_LIBRARY_PATH this time, but you can track down env var differences automatically using http://stromberg.dnsalias.org/~strombrg/env-search.html